# webpack 5 module.hot is undefined

Tags: reactjs, webpack, hot-module-replacement, webpack-5

I recently upgraded our react app to webpack5 and everything works fine but the browser error saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined` on this code:

```js
if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./Layout/Layout', () => {
        render();
    });
}
```

can anyone explain what happened and what I could do to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

in webpack5 all nodejs variable like `process` or `module` is removed so to get `module.hot` in webpack 5 you need to use `import.meta.webpackHot` and change your code to this:

```js
    if (import.meta.webpackHot) {
        import.meta.webpackHot.accept('./Layout/Layout', () => {
            render();
        });
    }
```